# A way to choose a block title's format (HTML tag)

Tags: 7, blocks

What I would like to do is be able to choose what type of Headline HTML element (h2, h3, etc) to use for each block's title. The only way I can find to change a block's Title is in block.tpl.php.  But this forces every block on the site to all have the same Headline.

I've Google'd and searched Drupal.org for a module or manual way to do this but have not found one. Does anyone know of a module that does this?
[image: would be cool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are asking about D7, but you are missing a key point about templates.  I'd take a gander at http://drupal.org/node/104319 which talks in great detail how D6 does it so you can how it can look at different block templates and then think about whether you need to create a module that has a configuration page for its blocks like what you have above or whether block location is enough.

Comment: block-[region].tpl.php would be the closest to what I'm looking for, but it still doesn't offer the level of cusomization I would like to offer my clients.  I want them or me to be able to simply place a piece of content anywhere with any headline level, using the "add block" link on the blocks admin page.

Comment: are you sure you are wanting to use blocks then?  how about a custom content type/node?  there you could have a content field widget'ed with checkboxes for your different h#s and then in your template do whatever you wanted based on that.

Comment: Would I then use Views to determine the display of the Content Type?  Is there another way as well?  I guess I wanted to use blocks because it's so straight forward and mostly built in to the out of the box functionality.

Comment: You would tell views what to do.  For example, if you created a content type 'special' with fields header_type, thumbnail, and description, views could display them based upon when they were posted, eg, chronologically, or ordered by header type (so, for example, h1s came first, or last, however you wanted).  And, with the same data, it could create another page (or block) with just the thumbnails in a grid that people could click on to get to the special.  All kinds of flexibility.

Comment: having some issues building this. How would the view build the HTML for the header_type around the actual text for the Headline.  I created 'header' and 'header_type' fields as the content fields.  I thought I could do it using replacement patterns in Views, but it doesn't work. I tried this `<[field_header_type]>[field_headline-value]</[field_header_type]>` but the output actually prints the `<` and `>` symbols rather than recognizing them as a part of an HTML tag.  Also, wouldn't I have to make a new View Display for every piece of content I want to place in the Admin Blocks page?

Comment: I would create a custom node template, outputting the appropriate html around the header field based on the header_type field.  If you've set up the values to be the h1, h2, etc, you can even output them like `$output .= '<' . $header_type . '>' . $header . '</' . $header_type . '>';` (or however it's set up :)

Comment: (or however  you want, `<<?php print $header_type; ?>><?php print $header; ?></<?php print $header_type; ?>>` is probably more in line with the code in a template, but certainly complicated to type in this comment given how many times I've edited my reply lol :)

Comment: I didnt know about node templates. I'll look it up. Thanks!

Comment: No matter what I try, I can't get the node template to work right.  using your code above sort of works, but depending on whether I use render() or not, it either wraps my values in all sorts of extra HTML, or simply displays the word `Array`.

Comment: Finally figured it out and posted my answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16811/custom-content-types-nodes-with-nodeblocks-module/