# Custom Content types nodes with Nodeblocks module

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I have been unsuccessful in accomplishing the following:

I am using the [Nodeblocks](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module and trying to follow its documentation for using it with a custom content type.  My custom content type machine name is `content_block`. I want a client to be able to create a new `content_block` and then be able to place it wherever he wants using the Admin > Blocks page.

The `content_block` content type has these fields (machine names - purpose):

- title - Title of the block (nodeblock) that will be seen on the Blocks administration page. Will be hidden from output.
- field_headline_level - stores a value like, "h2", "h3", "h4", etc. To be used to customize the HTML Headline tag. Will be hidden from output.
- field_headline - The actual words for the headline
- field_content - Content to be displayed below the headline

I've been trying to follow the Nodeblocks documentation (linked above) as well as the [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) but I can not get it to work.  I keep running into nested template problems, such as the default block template wrapping around the node type template and getting double headlines.  I also can't figure out the correct syntax to display the various `content_block` fields.

Can anyone out there help me out or point me to a "Node Templates for Dummies" article?  I've done lots of searches on Google, but can't find anything very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by getting my head around what Drupal calls "Template Suggestions".  The Theme Developer Module helped.

For my particular use case I had to create a template file called `block--nodeblock.tpl.php` to override the default block output. I basically stripped everything out of the default except the actual content so that this was all that was left: `<?php print $content ?>`.

Then I made a `node--content_block.tpl.php` template to override this particular content type's display the way I wanted it.  I had to add some trim() methods to strip out some leading spaces that Drupal insisted on inserting.

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

    <?php if($content['field_headline']): ?>
        <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
        <<?php print trim(render($content['field_headline_level'])) . ' ' . $title_attributes; ?>><?php print trim(render($content['field_headline'])); ?></<?php print trim(render($content['field_headline_level']));?>>
        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
        <?php print trim(render($content['field_content'])); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

The last thing I had to do was create a template to strip out all the extra tags that the Drupal default field comes with.  I did so with this file, named `field--content_block.tpl.php`:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
      <?php print render($item); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```